# What's wrong with this binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, styles

I'm trying to assign DataContext to a MenuItem, which is part of ListBox.

```
    <Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadListBox}, Path=DataContext}" />
    </Style>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateSelector">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Name="contentPresenter">
                <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                    <telerik:RadContextMenu>
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Connect" Click="RadMenuItem_Click" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ContextMenuStyle}" />
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Disconnect" />
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Delete Database" />
                    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
                </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            </ContentPresenter>
     </DataTemplate>


    <Grid>
        <telerik:RadListBox x:Name="lsbDevices" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Devices}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
```

Here's what I do. RadListBox's DataContext is set to my ViewModel. I want to assign this ViewModel to every RadMenuItem's DataContext through ContextMenuStyle, but it's not working. RadListBox's DataContext is properly set to my modelview, but RadMenuItem's datacontext is null. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContextMenus` are not part of the same `VisualTree` as the rest of the UI, so your `RelativeSource` binding is not finding the `ListBox`

You can find the UI object the `ContextMenu` is attached to by using the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadContextMenu}}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It looks like telerik changed their mind on this one, instead of `PlacementTarget` one should use `UIElement` now. And for those working with `RadTreeView`, the datacontext can be bound using `{Binding UIElement.ParentTreeView.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadContextMenu}}}` (please note the added _ParentTreeView_).