# Pass the item DataContext in CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I have a treeview which is created from `ItemsSource` of `SecondViewModel` instances, different from my Window DataContext.

I want to send the ViewModel that belongs to the TreeViewItem via a `CommandParameter.

The window data context is: `MyViewModel`.
The treeviewitems data context is: `SecondViewModel`

I want to pass the `SecondViewModel` and not `MyViewModel`.

Therefore,

```
CommandParameter ="{Binding}"
```

Won't work (as it will send `MyViewModel`)

Edit: Some Code:

```
 <TreeView Name="treeView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ProjectName}">
            <TreeViewItem commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding SelectOtherTab}" 
                          commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter="{Binding}" //this returns the data context of the window, I want to return the Item Source
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource AddClassMenu}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ClassDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassCollection}">
```

How can I send the `SecondViewModel`?

**EDIT:**

I want to enable deleting the current item, but the command never gets called for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
<TreeViewItem x:Name="treeViewItem"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource AddClassMenu}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ClassDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassCollection}">
                <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
              HERE->>          <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RemoveClassMenu}"/>
                        <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" 
        Value="{Binding ElementName=treeViewItem, Path=DataContext.SelectOtherTab}" />
                        <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" 
        Value="{Binding }" />
                    </Style>
</TreeViewItem>
```

My Context Menu:

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key="RemoveClassMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding ElementName=treeViewItem, Path=DataContext.RemoveClass}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

As mentions before, the command just never gets called. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: May I ask why you want the whole ItemSource to be bound in the CommandParameter? And how you set the ItemSource of the TreeView.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how your `SecondViewModel` relates to your `MyViewModel`, and where the `ItemsSource` comes in at. Can you include some more code showing how those 3 relate to each other? If you build your `TreeView` using an `ItemsSource` property instead of manually defining each `TreeViewItem`, then you can set your command behaviors in the `ItemContainerStyle` and `{Binding }` will refer to the each item in the `ItemsSource`. Right now, I don't see where your `SecondViewModel` is in your code at all.

Comment: @MatsMagnem I don't want the whole ItemSource, just the one who relates to the treeviewitem. (1 item)

Comment: @Rachel I'm sorry, I said 'SecondViewModel' just so it will be easier to understand, it is actually the ItemSource - ClassCollection, the ClassCollection is an observablecollection created from ClassViewModel (This is actually the SecondViewModel I used as an example before).

Comment: @idish Can't you use `{Binding ClassCollection}` instead of `{Binding }` to pass it your SecondViewModel?

Comment: @Rachel That's what I want to ask, can I?

Comment: @Rachel Isn't it going to send as parameter the whole collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking to do is set your `DoubleClick` commands on your child `TreeViewItems`, not your parent `TreeViewItem` which sets the `ItemsSource`

Right now your XAML is saying to build a parent `TreeViewItem`, and under that build a bunch of child `TreeViewItems` for each item in `ClassCollection`. When you double click on the parent `TreeViewItem` then run the `SelectOtherTab` command, however there's nothing to specify which child `TreeViewItem` got clicked.

Here's a simplified view of the XAML you have now.

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab"> <!-- Parent TreeViewItem -->
        <TreeViewItem /><!-- Child TreeViewItems -->
        <TreeViewItem />
        <TreeViewItem />
        ...
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Instead you want to attach the `Command` and `CommandParameter` properties to each child  `TreeViewItem`, like this:

```
<TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" 
            Value="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=DataContext.SelectOtherTab}" />
    <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" 
            Value="{Binding }" />
  </Style>
</TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Which will make your simplified XAML look something like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeViewItem> <!-- Parent TreeViewItem -->
        <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab" /><!-- Child TreeViewItems -->
        <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab"/>
        <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab" />
        ...
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

I'm still a bit confused by why you have a parent `TreeViewItem` and are building child `TreeViewItems` using it's `ItemsSource`, however if that's not necessary you can simplify your VisualTree by eliminating the parent `TreeViewItem` like this:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ClassCollection}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"  
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="ProjectName" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource AddClassMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ClassDataTemplate}" />

            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" 
                    Value="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=DataContext.SelectOtherTab}" />
            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" 
                    Value="{Binding }" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Which will make your TreeView look like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab" />
    <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab"/>
    <TreeViewItem OnDoubleClick="SelectOtherTab" />
    ...
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Wow, I really apperciate your effort helping me, thank you!          I'm so sorry.. I guess I made a mistake.. that lead you giving me a solution for something I didn't want. I don't want only the parent treeviewitem to be able to click on, I want the opposite, I want to enable all it's child items to be able to click and implement the command. On that way, each treeviewitem(the child items) is built from the ClassCollection Items. I just want to pass the ViewModel that is "responsible" for the item. Thank you once again, sorry for my bad English, let me know if anything is incomprehensible

Comment: @idish I think so :) The code I posted will make it so that each `TreeViewItem` that is generated from `ClassCollection` will have a doubleClick event that calls `SelectOtherTab`, and passes the item from `ClassCollection` in as a parameter

Comment: Then yes, it is. Great! I'm going to try it out in a few. BTW, about your last tip with the treeview, I'm not doing that, because I have another set of TreeViewItem(I showed only the neccasary code).

Comment: @idish I was wondering if that was the case because of your `Header` binding. Let me know how it goes though :)

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you so much, really, you helped me understand a little more how WPF works.. I'm pretty new to that, I started around 2 weeks ago. Anyway, thanks alot!

Comment: Can you just explain me please why in the Path it is Path="DataContext.SelectOtherTab" and not Path="SelectOtherTab"?

Comment: Rachel, I would be very thankfull if you could help me with my other little problem(refers to same context). Please see my edited post.

Comment: @idish ContextMenus are not part of the same VisualTree as the rest of your application, so Bindings can't find their values. You'll need to use `PlacementTarget` in your bindings to find the `TreeViewItem`, then find your command from there. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211901/302677) for an example

Answer (score 0):

you must declare a property of type SecondViewModel in MyViewModel.then you can bind the data to inner items too.

CommandParameter ="{Binding SecondViewModelProp.CommandParam}"

if command parameter is defined inside the SecondViewModelProp.

Let me know if I understood something wrong.

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
    public SecondViewModel  SecondViewModelProp
    {
        get { return new SecondViewModel(); }
    }

   public MyViewModel()
   {

   }
 }
```

Comment: If I'll declare a property of type SecondViewModel, how can I bind it to my treeviewitem's commandparameter?

Comment: Hmm sorry, didn't realy understand. What is SecondViewModelProp? What will this property do? and what is the CommandParam?

Comment: SecondViewModelProp  is property for the  SecondViewModel inside myViewModel.

Comment: But what will it return? I want to return the current SecondViewModel(the one who is responsible for the treeviewitem)

Comment: Ahh, sorry for digging too much, but I want to understand before I try, how would getting new SecondViewModel will help me? I want to return the current existing SecondViewModel.(It is already inside an observableCollection)